# If statement in Postscript

Tags: if-statement, postscript

How to create if function in Poscript.

If (1.ps is filename) open fucntion /1 
If (2.ps is filename) open function /1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXUgZ.png)

Comment: You need to give us more information. What PostScript language interpreter are you using: a printer? if so, what model? Adobe Acrobat Distiller? Ghostscript? If so, what version?   And how does the PostScript language file get to the interpreter? And how does the interpreter get run?  
If you are printing a document to a printer which has a built-in interpreter, that is one situation. If you have a batch file sending disk-resident files to GhostScript, that is a much different situation.

Answer (score 4):

Please read the PostScript Language Reference Manual, the if and ifelse operators are well defined there.

For example (based on the example on page 607 of the 3rd edition):

```
4 3 lt
{
  (TruePart) print
}
{
  (FalsePart) print
}
ifelse
```

Run this through a PostScript interpreter and it will print 'FalsePart', because 4 is not less than 3.

If you want to program in PostScript, you will need to learn the basics of the language. The code you've pointed at isn't valid PostScript.

Comment: of coure it do not work. But could you improve it and give me some hints?

I have to check if current filename is the same as declared filename. 
Screen: [link](http://imgur.com/a/N2Kju)

Program: 
currentfile .filename pop show

/CorrectFileName 1.ps def 

.filename CorrectFileName eq {
 true part 
} 
{
 false part 
}
ifelse

Comment: let's start with: Use `(1.ps)` to define a string constant.

Comment: The rest is ok? 

Can I for true part, paste code of .eps file?

Comment: No, the rest is completely wrong, the only part which is correct is the bit you copied from the example. .filename is a Ghostscript-specific operator, its an extension to the language and will not work on any other interpreter. You cannot compare two strings directly for equivalence, they will only be equal if they are the same string object (in C terms, if they are char pointers to the same piece of memory). Two strings declared as 'string' in PostScript will not be the same. If you want to check if the contents are the same then you need to check each character in each string.

Comment: If you are trying to learn some PostScript then start with the Blue and Green books, I also reccomend John Deubert's excellent Acumen Training site. http://www.acumentraining.com/acumenjournal.html

Comment: I need post script exactly only one time in my life, and it is now, and I need it for tomorrow, so I try do it this way because I do not have enough time to read whole book. Thanks for answers. 

I am using Ghostscript. 

The whole think is that: I have to make a program, in which when file 1.ps is opened, 1.eps is opened, when file 2.ps is opened 2.eps is opened.

Comment: You probably should, instead of copying an eps file in, just `(epsfilename) run` inside the true part, but you would usually have to do some positioning/scaling of the eps, and put `gsave`/`grestore` around to not mess up the gstate for the following code. BTW statements like "I need it tomorrow" might be true for you, but are kind of inappropriate on SO. We're not paid to do your job and are sorry if you have to do magic you don't know. You'd have to discuss that with your boss I'm afraid.